# Appending data to Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a Map

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> entireData;
```

Now to this I'm adding some data using putAll like

```
entireData.putAll(someData);
```

where someData returns `Map<Integer, List<Object>>`

Now, I have another line which says

```
entireData.putAll(someMoreData);
```

which also returns `Map<Integer, List<Object>>`, but by doing this it over-writes the content of the existing entireData, how do I append?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First line of the Java Map Class Reference:

> An object that maps keys to values. A
>   map cannot contain duplicate keys;
>   each key can map to at most one value.

Comment: true, i agree, the key values are different here though

Comment: Hmmm, that's not supposed to happen!  putAll() is the same as calling put() for all items in the source collection.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question though, you asked about appending and you got a bunch of legitimate answers.

Answer (score 7):

You want a [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Rewriting your example with Guava Multimap:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Object> entireData = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

`entireData.get(key)` returns a `List<Object>`. `putAll` will not override old keys but will append the values of those keys to the existing values. This is also much nicer than dealing with initializing the `List` instances yourself.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (Integer key : someMoreData.keySet())
{
    if (entireData.containsKey(key))
    {
        entireData.get(key).addAll(someMoreData.get(key));
    }
    else
    {
        entireData.put(key, someMoreData.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keys are unique. If `someMoreData` has a key same as already existing key in `entireData` the value i.e. list of object will be overwritten.

However you can loop in `someMoreData` and append for keys that exists in `entireData` like

```
 for(Integer key: someMoreData.keySet()){
       if(entireData.get(key)!=null)
           entireData.get(key).addAll(someMoreData.get(key));
       else
           entireData.put(key,someMoreData.get(key));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Per default, Java Maps map one key to one value, [as trojanfoe writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613386/appending-data-to-map-in-java/4613401#4613401). If that is not sufficient to your needs, you need a Multi-Map implementation (A Map that maps from a key to a collection of values).

The most popular versions can be found in two open source Frameworks, [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and [Apache Commons / Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

**Guava Example:**

```
final Multimap<Integer, String> mmap =
    Multimaps.newSetMultimap(
        Maps.<Integer, Collection<String>> newHashMap(),
        new Supplier<Set<String>>(){

            @Override
            public Set<String> get(){
                return Sets.newHashSet();
            }
        });
mmap.put(1, "foo");
mmap.put(1, "bar");
System.out.println(mmap.get(1));
```

Output:

> [foo, bar]

**Commons Collections Example:**

```
final MultiMap mmap = new MultiHashMap();
mmap.put(1, "foo");
mmap.put(1, "bar");
System.out.println(mmap.get(1));
```

Output:

> [foo, bar]

As you can see, the Commons Collections version is a lot simpler, but it's also less powerful, and in the current version it doesn't support Java 1.5 generics. So I'd go with Guava.

Comment: You can instantiate a Guava `Multimap` _much_ more simply using one of `Multimaps.new[(Linked?Hash)|Tree]Multimap.create()` (ok, maybe that "regex" isn't perfect ;-)

Comment: ...at any rate, +1 for demonstrating how to get the generics right with `newSetMultimap(Maps.newHashMap(), ...)` which is what ***I*** needed.

Answer (score 0):

similar to [willcodejavaforfood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51382/willcodejavaforfood)'s no dependencies needed answer but using an entrySet instead for less HashMap retrievals.

```
public static <K,V> void appendMapBtoMapA(HashMap<K,List<V>> a, HashMap<K,List<V>> b) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, List<V>> bEntry : b.entrySet()) {
        if (a.containsKey(bEntry.getKey())) {
            a.get(bEntry.getKey()).addAll(bEntry.getValue());
        } else {
            a.put(bEntry.getKey(), bEntry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

or [Nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298455/nishant)'s which drops a contains call and adds a null check but with entrySet

```
public static <K,V> void appendMapBtoMapA(HashMap<K,List<V>> a, HashMap<K,List<V>> b) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, List<V>> bEntry : b.entrySet()) {
        List<V> aValue = a.get(bEntry.getKey());
        if (aValue != null) {
            aValue.addAll(bEntry.getValue());
        } else {
            a.put(bEntry.getKey(), bEntry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

or with java 8

```
public static <K,V> void appendMapBtoMapA(HashMap<K,List<V>> a, HashMap<K,List<V>> b) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, List<V>> bEntry : b.entrySet()) {
        a.computeIfAbsent(
            bEntry.getKey(), 
            k -> new LinkedList<>()
        ).addAll(bEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```